# How do I find the 10 largest subarrays efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I need to find 10 largest subarrays (maximum length) in an array with the condition `arr[high] - arr[low] < delta`. It's taking 50 seconds right now (using Python). I'm able to find the maximum sub-array by modifying the algorithm to find maximum subarray with `sum < somevalue`. Right now, I'm just using a for loop and deleting the maximum sub-array found after every iteration. I tried a lot of things but am back to this now as nothing worked correctly. The array is sorted.

```
with open(in_file) as f_in, open(out_file, 'w') as f_out:
    dct = {}        
    mainlst = []
    # Read a file and store values in mainlst and map to some strings using dct

    for i in range(10): 
        start = 0
        end = 0
        maxim = 0
        diff = 0
        current = 1
        max_start = 0
        max_end = 0
        while end < len(mainlst)-1:
            end += 1
            diff = mainlst[end] - mainlst[start]                
            current += 1
            while diff > delta:
                start += 1
                diff = mainlst[end] - mainlst[start]
                current -= 1
            if maxim < current:
                maxim = current
                max_start = start
                max_end = end

        print("".join([dct[mainlst[max_start]], ",", str(maxim)]), file=f_out)

        del mainlst[max_start:max_end+1]
```

Edit: I forgot to mention another condition. The sub-arrays cannot overlap.

Comment: do you mean you have an array of arrays and want to find 10 longest ones?

Comment: No I have one array and need to find longest sub-arrays.

Comment: It takes 50 seconds for what size of input?

Comment: 4400644 values in mainlst

Comment: Iterating over the input 10 times is clearly the thing to avoid.

Comment: Yeah. I'm just wondering if there's a better way to do it without iterating 10 times. Or maybe considering the size of the input file (380MB text file) 50  is the best? I'm also doing some work with parsing the input file where I've commented.

Comment: "I'm just wondering if there's a better way to do it without iterating 10 times." Store a list of the top 10. As you encounter subarrays matching your range, look at the size. If it's longer than one of the current top 10, replace the smallest.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `O(N lg N)` algorithm:

1. Iterate through each element, from small to large, set current element to `A[low]`, `O(N)`
2. Binary search the index of `A[high]` which fulfill the inequality, `O(lg N)`
3. Push the length and the pair of `(low, high)` in a priority queue or any data structure which maintained order in `O(lg N)` times
4. Pop the top 10, or top `N` items and that's the answer

**EDITED**

Thanks to @m69, using two pointers a better `O(N)` can be achieved:

1. Iterate through each element, from small to large, set two pointers `low` and `high` pointing to the first element initially
2. Move the `high` pointer to the right until `A[high] - A[low] >= delta`, push the length and the pair of `(low, high)` in a priority queue or any data structure which maintained order in `O(lg N)` times.

   For your special case, you can simply use an array of size 10 to store the longest 10 subarray, then you can use `O(1)` to maintain this array.
3. Move `low` pointer to right , repeat step 2.

Note that `low` is always smaller than or equal to `high`, and both pointers always move to right only, each iterate through the list once. So it is `O(N)`, or it is `O(N lg N)` for general case using priority queue.

Comment: The binary search is unnecessary; the high pointer only moves upwards.